# Count the number of rows that each word appears in

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a training dataset that is a numpy array, and has the shape of (4800,1). It has a column of strings, and each row correspond to the texts from a different email.

I want to create a dictionary that counts the number of emails (or number of rows) each word appears in using python. And eventually only select the words that appear in at least 10 emails. I could only figure out how to count the frequency of the words appearing in the entire dataset, not in how many rows/emails. The following code is what i have so far

Here is an example of what the array looks like, and what it should output.

```
 [['red blue green green']
 ['red blue blue'] 
 ['red red red']]
```

output:

```
{'red': 3, 'blue': '2', 'green': '1'}
```

```py
def vocab_dict(file):
    d = dict() 
    for row in xTrain:
        words = row.split(" ") 
        for word in words: 
            if word in d: 
                d[word] = d[word] + 1
            else: 
                d[word] = 1
    d = dict((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v >= 10)
    return d
```

I am stuck on how to modify the above code that counts how many times a word appears in the whole dataset to how many times a word appears in each row(each email).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate over each line, and for each *unique* word in that sentence, add one to the dict element representing that word. You can get the unique words by converting the list to a `set`.

```
def vocab_dict(data):
    lines_count = {}
    for line in data:
        for word in set(line.split()):
            old_count = lines_count.get(word, 0)
            lines_count[word] = old_count + 1
    return lines_count
```

The `dict.get()` function returns the value of that key, with a default of 0 if the key doesn't exist. Alternatively, you could use `collections.defaultdict`.

Testing:

```
l = ['red blue green green', 'red blue blue', 'red red red']
vocab_dict(l)
# Out:  {'green': 1, 'blue': 2, 'red': 3}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is so clear, I understood immediately. this worked perfectly. I just had to add a line before return that deletes those that are less than 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a list of strings `l`. Then we can do:

```
from collections import Counter

word_lists = [text.split(" ") for text in l] # split into words
word_sets = [set(word_list) for word_list in word_lists] # make sets, discard duplicates

c = Counter()
for word_set in word_sets:
    c.update(word_set)
print(c)
```

`c` will now contain, for each word, the number of emails that that word is in.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the `words` list into a set so that it gets rid of the repetition. You can do it like:

```
[...]
for word in set(words):
    if word in d:
    [...]
```

Comment: This won't work, as words is a list of full texts. This will only discard duplicate emails, not duplicate words.

Comment: @Anonymous1847  - `words` refers to a list of the words in each row (`words = rows.split(' ')`)

Comment: I assume you mean `words = row.split(' ')`?